# How to write xarray dataset with complex objects like dictionaries in the array values?

Tags: python, python-xarray

I have an xarray dataset:

```
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr

data_1 = np.random.randn(2, 2)
lon = [175.25, 176.75]
lat = [25.75, 26.25]

ds_1 = xr.Dataset(data_vars=dict(variable=(["lon", "lat"], data_1)),
                  coords=dict(lon=(["lon"], lon),
                              lat=(["lat"], lat),),)
```

and a dictionary as follow:

```
keys = ['n', 'K', 'data']

values_1 = [177.0, 25, [{'m': 201.22, 'c': 4.0}, {'m': 201.47, 'c': 4.0}]]
dictionary_1 = dict(zip(keys, values_1))

values_2 = [152.0, 25, [{'m': 221.62, 'c': 4.0}, {'m': 261.27, 'c': 4.0}]]
dictionary_2 = dict(zip(keys, values_2))
```

Now I would like to write a `xarray` dataset that has `lon`, `lat` (from `ds_1`), and my dictionaries. In the end, I need to extract the data in this order for each lon/lat:

```
{'n': 177.0, 'K': 25, 'data': [{'m': 201.22, 'c': 4.0}, {'m': 201.47, 'c': 4.0}]}
```

I have been stuck here, and I appreciate any help. This is what I have done:

```
ds_2 = xr.Dataset(
    {"data": dictionary_1.get("data"), },
    coords={
        "lon": ds_1.lon[0].values,
        "lat": ds_1.lat[0].values,
        "n": dictionary_1.get("n"),
        "K": dictionary_1.get("K")},)
```

Comment: Sorry - I’m not sure exactly what you need help with. Can you be more specific about what isn’t working about what you’ve tried? We’re not a code-writing service - please try to do what you’re looking for and then if you get stuck or run into errors feel free to provide a [mre], full tracebacks for errors, etc.

Comment: Dear @MichaelDelgado thanks for your comment. I modified the description of the question with a reproducible example.

Comment: Sorry I still don’t understand what you’re trying to do. Your dictionary format doesn’t make sense to me, so it’s not obvious to me how to translate the dataset into this format. I also don’t really understand what the issue you’re facing is - you seem to be extracting some of the data just fine but you’re having trouble doing the same thing again with the 1 index rather than the 0 index? Can you just break down the issue into individual parts so we can help with the first step, e.g. “how to select the 2nd element”? Rather than trying to solve your whole problem at once - that may help clarify

Comment: Let's make it simpler. The `dictionary_1` is related to the `lon/lat` of `ds_1`. But in the current form, they are in two different formats and two different datasets. 
My desired format is to have the dictionary_1 and the respective `lon/lat` in a simple `xarray` format. So for example when I call `ds_2['data'][0, 0]`, be able to see the entire dictionary.

Comment: You want the xarray variable to hold dictionaries?

Comment: @MichaelDelgado 
Yes, that would be the ideal situation (holding the dictionaries). But I am not sure if `xarray` can do it in a simple way as I described above.

Comment: I strongly recommend against it. You can assign a numpy array with dtype=object to a DataArray, but neither numpy nor xarray are designed to handle arbitrary containers inside the array. Performance will certainly suffer, you may not be able to read and write the data depending on your storage format, and many operations will stop working. I would design a different workflow or use an object storage format like json.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelDelgado for your explanation. I should design a different workflow, xarray is not a good choice for this particular case purpose.